# Can someOne tell me a brief Comparison between versions of LCDS

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, blazeds, lcds

We are using Adobe LCDS 2.1 and thinking of Upgrading it to a higher version.. can someone tell me a brief Comparison of the LCDS versions available (3.1 , 4.1....) ????

Comment: I would expect release notes to contain such info. Did you have a look at them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last version is 3.1 You need to read the documents from [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/documentation.html#task=0,1,2,3,4,5,6&module=5) url in order to understand what are the new features (the release is good but is not enough), and after that it would be good to try building a prototype (if you plan to use the data modeling for example) to see how they will fit into your current architecture.

I wouldn't do any upgrade unless there is a business reason (bugs, poor performance, luck of productivity) - for any product.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you'd need a comparison for 'all versions' if you can only purchase the latest one.  I suggest you look at the l[atest version's whitepaper](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/pdfs/lces2_5_tech_wp_ue.pdf) so that you can see what's been added.  The biggest thing IMO is better integration for all clients, different messaging protocols and well as much needed bug fixes (I remember 2.1 had some fairly obvious bugs).

Comment: i just need to present a report about the changes made in the newer versions,or Pros and cons of the Different versions so they gonna decide which version they will buy..Thanks in advance

Comment: Again, I don't think it's even a choice.  You can only buy the latest version.  Since you're probably going to be dropping a lot of money for this, I say talk to a [sales rep directly](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/) instead of spending time here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the choice is "should we upgrade or not?"

I'd say it may also be worth considering what you're doing with LCDS -- if you're only using it for things like Flash Remoting, is it possible that you could go the other route and 'downgrade' the the open source BlazeDS?  It has a lot fewer features, but might do what you need, and be a lot cheaper.

Here's a comparison of BlazeDS to LCDS ES2: http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/dataservices/compare.html

I'm not familiar with prior releases of LCDS, so I can't offer any better advice about comparing versions than the previous respondents. Basically: Check the release notes =)

Comment: Even for remoting sometimes is not possible to use BlazeDS..Adobe does not offer paid support so for some companies is not an option.